# How can I create a command line definition for a public code module without cloning it?

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

Specifically, I want to define `WBT_USEAUTOLOGON` for `$(_PUBLICROOT)\RDP\OAK\UIT\TSCONWIZ`

This would get the functionality I require without having to clone the module(s).

I expect I can use a trick like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2010/03/23/platform-builder-cloning--the-linker-is-your-friend.aspx) to get around it, but I'd prefer an even more elegant way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there isn't a better way to achieve this. I ended up cloning only the files which make use of the definition and adding the definition to the CDEFINES in the sources files of `TSCONWIZ` and `TSCONMAN`.

if you want to do a minimal clone, see my question's link to Bruce's blog for details.